# External table is not in the expected format OLEDB 12.0 with Excel 2007

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have developed a WEB API service which will read data from excel file when user upload.

I use OLEDB as following:

```
if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToUpper() == ".XLS")
{
    oledbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\"");
}
else
{
    oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";");
}
oledbConn.Open();  //Exception thrown at here
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
cmd.Connection = oledbConn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT(["+mo_field+"]),["+model_field+"],["+content_filed+"] FROM ["+ecn_field+"] WHERE ["+mo_field+"] IS NOT NULL AND ["+active_field+"] ='1'";
oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
oleda.Fill(ds,"NewMO");
```

but it thrown exception:

> External table is not in the expected format

My server is installed Window Server 2012 RC2 64 bit so I have tried install Microsoft Database Engine 2010 redistribute 32bit/64bit. And Microsoft Database Engine 2007 32 bit. But it still does not work. I searched for 3 days, and every posts said that install Microsoft Database Engine will fix the error. This code work well with Office 2010/2013.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Does it work if you type in the path where it says "+ filePath +"?

Comment: It doesn't work, too :)

Comment: After you Fill the DataSet (ds), you can try creating a DataTable and then using that:  DataTable dt= ds.Tables[0];

Comment: It thrown exception at `oledbConn.Open();` so it does not run to Fill the dataset

Comment: you can remove the `Xml` from the connection string. It is only for `.xlsx` files

Comment: Also, the `Jet.OLEDB.4.0` provider is not supported on 64 bit windows, so just use the `ACE.OLEDB.12` for any excel files.

Comment: @Slai: I have fixed as your suggestion but it still doesn't work

Comment: I tried your code with Excel 2013 and it worked fine.  The one thing that Office is picky about is trying to open a file that is already open, so make sure that you do not have the file open.  Also, it is a good idea to wrap everything in a "using" statement -     using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
    {}

Comment: In my question, I noticed that it worked well with Excel 2010 and Excel 2013. But in my company, almost computer is using Excel 2007 so I have to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ds = new DataSet();
var da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT(["+mo_field+"]),["+model_field+"],["+content_filed+"] FROM ["+ecn_field+"] WHERE ["+mo_field+"] IS NOT NULL AND ["+active_field+"] ='1'", 
                              "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + filePath + "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'");
da.Fill(ds,"NewMO");
```

and make sure that the file is really an Excel file by opening it in Excel.

**Update**

Here are few more connection strings from https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/ to try

```
foreach (var cs in new string[] {
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES';",
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0; HDR = Yes; IMEX = 1';" })
    try { using (var con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(cs)) con.Open(); MessageBox.Show(cs + " worked bro!!"); } catch { }

foreach (var cs in new string[] {
    "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" + filePath + ";",
    "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq=" + filePath + ";",
    "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};Dbq=" + filePath + ";ReadOnly=0;"})
    try { using (var con = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(cs)) con.Open(); MessageBox.Show(cs + " worked bro!!"); } catch { }
```

Comment: It thrown exception at `oledbConn.Open();`. And the code work well with Excel 2010/2013, bro

Comment: that strange because there is no `oledbConn.Open();` in my code :] so I guess you did not try it?

Comment: I tried your code and still got exception at `da.Fill(ds,"NewMO");`. I am so confused :(.

Comment: can you open the file in Notepad and check what the first few characters are?

Comment: Here is the first characters, bro: `ÐÏ`

Comment: `ÐÏà¡±á` is The Excel 97 - Excel 2003 Binary file format (BIFF8) so the file seems ok. From what I found online, the problem might be if you installed the 2007 driver after the 2010 one, so you can try repairing the Microsoft Database Engine 2010 driver.

Comment: @MrNeo which ones worked or any idea what the problem was? It might help me or someone else with similar problem.

Comment: I tried your first solution and check the Excel file. My `.xlsx` file is  Excel 97 - Excel 2003 Binary file format, the creator had just only changed file extension from `.xls` to `.xlsx`.

Answer (score 0):

i am having similar problem. my code is below

```
OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Xls Files (*.xls)|*xls|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv"
OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
txtFilePath.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
Dim filepath As String = txtFilePath.Text
Dim conn As String = String.Empty
If filepath.EndsWith(".xls") Or filepath.EndsWith(".xlsx") Or filepath.EndsWith(".csv") Or filepath.EndsWith("(.csv)") _
    Or filepath.EndsWith("*.xlsm") Or filepath.EndsWith("*.xlsb") Then
    conn = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; " &
                       "Data Source ={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=yes'", filepath)
Else
    conn = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0; " &
                      "Data Source ={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=yes'", filepath)
End If
Dim connString As New OleDbConnection(conn)
connString.Open()
cboSheets.DataSource = connString.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
cboSheets.DisplayMember = "Table_Name"
cboSheets.ValueMember = "Table_Name"
connString.Close()
```

End Sub

Comment: Did this code solve your issue? If so, could you [edit] your answer to explain what you’re doing?